# Camera Intent giving Exception in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi i am new for android and in my app I have recorded video and when i get recorded video intent data i am getting exception in my LG mobile and my Nexus this problem is not coming

can some one help me please

```
    private void recordVideo() {

        try {

            String tempTimestamp = "" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis());
            File mediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/" + tempTimestamp + ".mp4");
            fileName = tempTimestamp + ".mp4";

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
            System.out.println("file uri is====>" + fileUri);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);

        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {

            if (requestCode == Constants.VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    if (data.getData() != null) {


                    } else {

                        if (data.getExtras().get("data") != null) {
                            data.getExtras().get("data");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

### Exception:-

```
11-05 05:06:12.859 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at com.ensis.epatient.Gallery.VideosAttachmentActivity.onActivityResult(VideosAttachmentActivity.java:283)
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6258)
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3685)
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3732)
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:162)
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431)
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient I/Activity: Activity.onPostResume() called 
11-05 05:06:12.869 26942-26942/com.ensis.epatient W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

Comment: NullPointerException Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
if (data.getData() != null) {

} else {
    if (data.getExtras().get("data") != null) {
        data.getExtras().get("data");
    }
}
```

to:

```
if (data != null) {
    if (data.getExtras() != null) {
        if (data.getExtras().get("data") != null) {
           data.getExtras().get("data");
        }
    }
} else {
    // do someting if data is null 
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

Comment: @AbhiRam see updated answer. You need to check if data is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` for camera intent the uotput is stored in that file. The data returned in `onActivityResult()` will be null.

You can use the `fileUri` that you have passed for `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` to access image or video captured by camera.

```
if (requestCode == Constants.VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (fileUri != null) {
                // check here if that file exists 
                // if yes get that file and use as per requirement
                } 
            }
        }
```